# Set Focus for Primefaces Component in Bean with WidgetVar with RequestContex Execute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, focus

Is there a way to set my component focus after an function call to an other component with Primefaces RequestContex?

i tried:

```
RequestContex.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('WidgetVar').focus();");
```

and

```
RequestContex.getCurrentInstance().execute("(((InputText) event.getComponent()).getWidgetVar()).focus();");
```

I dont get an error but nothing happens.

Did i miss something or is this not possible?

I use Primefaces 4.0.3 and MyFaces 2.0.2

**EDIT** Example Code

*Bean*

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

public class NavigationBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String input;

    public NavigationBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    }

    public void goNext() {
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().warning("GONEXT");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().scrollTo("w3");

    }

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

}
```

XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>


</h:head>

<h:body >

<h:form id="form">
<h:inputText id="input1" value="#{navigationBean.input}" widgetVar="w1"></h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="input2" value="#{navigationBean.input}" widgetVar="w2"></h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="input3" value="#{navigationBean.input}" widgetVar="w3"></h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="input4" value="#{navigationBean.input}" widgetVar="w4"></h:inputText>
    <p:commandButton value="focus" action="#{navigationBean.goNext()}" />

</h:form>


</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: try `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("$('#input4').focus();");`

Comment: @jerith2: how is this comment fundamentally different to one of the answers already given? The one you edited? Please upvote that answer if you think it is the best one

Comment: @Kukeltje , beginners might think that, javascript function need to created to address the focus issue, so to make clear that its not required i gave the solution in comment. Reason for edited the answer is # tag was not provided in solution so people end up in trial and error scenario of using ID and Widgetvar, hope this is clear !

Comment: @jerith2: Then add that as a comment to the answer, not the question. You can even improve the answer and add you can also do it without a function

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<p:focus>` tag from primefaces, I used it for setting focus at run time as follows :

.xhtml code:

```xml
<p:focus id="focusID" for="#{yourBean.focusProperty}" />
```

.java code:

```java
focusProperty="componentIDToSetFocus";
```

don't forget to update the ID of `<p:focus>` tag

Answer (score 3):

If the previous answer does not work, you can create a js function, for example:

```
function focusField(id){
 $(id).focus();
}
```

Then in your bean, assuming u want set focus on field "input4" , it represents ID not Widgetvar

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("focusField('#input4');");
```

Answer (score 3):

Using PrimeFaces 6.1, for reasons unknown, I was unable to get the primefaces p:focus to work.  So, I just implemented an onload JQuery function to set focus to a p:commandButton.  For the onload call, put the jQuery nested function below in the 'body'.  This is to be sure to override any other primefaces onload functions.

```
<script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          jQuery(document).ready(function () {
              // twice in document.ready to 
              // execute after Primefaces callbacks
              PF('widget_home_page_form_command_button').getJQ().focus();
          });
     });
</script>
```

PrimeFaces creates widgetVar components for all of the primefaces components.  Some features are available though the widgetVar such as disable or enable.  But, I had to  use the getJQ() function to obtain the jQuery object and used that object to set focus on the command button.

Comment: If you have a problem not getting the `p:focus` to work, you can always try to create your own question (and answer that yourself) instead of providing an answer that is only very slightly related to the question you try to answer. For me, `p:focus` works in 6.1 in the way I use it, so it is certainly not a generic issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're under a couple of misconceptions here:

1. That you can execute *Java* code in `RequestContext` API.

   ```
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("(((InputText) event.getComponent()).getWidgetVar()).Focus();");
   ```

   You can't. The code above will not work. `execute` is built for *JavaScript* only.
2. The function name you're looking for is `focus()`. JS is case-sensitive. So `Focus <> focus`. So I think what you should have there is

   ```
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("yourClientSideId.focus();");
   ```

   Where `yourClientSideId`should correspond to the `widgetVar` attribute of the component you're interested in. I'm not sure what the `PF` object you're referencing in your code is supposed to be. I've never seen it. Perhaps you meant the `PrimeFaces` object?

In the event of failure of the above, you could always use the `scrollTo` method on `RequestContext`:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().scrollTo("yourComponentWidgetVar");
```

Comment: Iam not sure if PF stands for Primefaces Object but since 4.0 they used a new syntax to access widgetVars. I got this from the dialog example on the primefaces page so i thought a try wouldnt hurt. Unfortunately  the code isnt working for me. I tried widget and id.

Comment: @Shibas - you're unable to use `scrollTo` too?

Comment: i added my code. I want to switch the focus between the input boxes with a button or an other event inside of the bean. scrollTo does not work thats right.

Comment: RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().scrollTo("widgetVarName"); not  working, screen hangs