# Can I have two <p:focus> tag in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want my webpage to focus on the field which need more action. I follow [this](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/focus.xhtml) example to achieve it, it works perfectly by using `<p:focus context="panel"/>` tag. If there is any field requires value and is empty, it will auto focus on that particular field.
The problem comes when I want to set focus from bean. I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36667198/4541141) by using `<p:focus id="focusID" for="#{yourBean.focusProperty}" />` to set focus, it works, but the first tag `<p:focus context="panel"/>` not working anymore. Which means when there is required field is empty, it will not focus on that field, instead, it will always focus on the first field of my form. Below is my code:

```
<p:panel id="formPanel" header="Register">
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" globalOnly="true" />
    <p:focus context="formPanel" />
    <h:form>
        <p:focus id="focusID" for="#{registerBean.focusProperty}"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
            <p:outputLabel for="name" value="Name: " />
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{registerBean.profile.name}" required="true"/>
            <p:message for="name"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="tp" value="TP: " />
            <p:inputText id="tp" value="#{registerBean.student.tp}" required="true"/>
            <p:message for="tp"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="email" value="Email: " />
            <p:inputText id="email" value="#{registerBean.account.email}" required="true"/>
            <p:message for="email"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="username" value="Username: " />
            <p:inputText id="username" value="#{registerBean.account.username}" required="true"/>
            <p:message for="username"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: " />
            <p:password id="password" value="#{registerBean.account.password}" required="true" />
            <p:message for="password"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="confirmPassword" value="Confirm Password: " />
            <p:password id="confirmPassword" value="#{registerBean.confirmPassword}" required="true" />
            <p:message for="confirmPassword"/>

            <p:commandButton value="Register" action="#{registerBean.register()}" update="formPanel"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
```

**RegisterBean.java**

```
public String register()
{
    System.out.println("register");
    String accountValidateResult = accountService.validate(account);
    String studentValidateResult = studentService.validate(student);
    System.out.println("Validation Result: " + accountValidateResult);
    if (!studentValidateResult.isEmpty())
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", studentValidateResult + " has been taken"));
        focusProperty = studentValidateResult.toLowerCase();
        return null;
    }
    if (!accountValidateResult.isEmpty())
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", accountValidateResult + " has been taken"));
        focusProperty = accountValidateResult.toLowerCase();
        return null;
    }
    profile = profileService.insert(profile);
    account.setProfileId(profile.getId());
    student.setProfileId(profile.getId());
    accountService.insert(account);
    studentService.insert(student);

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Registration Successful", "Please login to you account"));
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
    return "index?faces-redirect=true";
}
```