# Primefaces set focus from bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

If I want set focus to the field which has failed to validate. I can use `<p:focus context='@form'/>` to achieve this simple case, easy. But my problem is, not all validation can be performed at the front-end. For example, I want a user to enter a username, when the user submits the form, bean will check the database whether the username already exists or not, if exist, set error message to the field and set focus to it as well. In this case, the `<p:focus />` tag does not work anymore since it actually has passed the front-end validation.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36667198/4541141) answer and try to implement it, I would say that it only works partially. Why? because if you set focus manually from bean by declaring a variable for it, it will override the `<p:focus context='@form'/>` tag. When this focus tag lost its function, if there is any front-end validation failed, it will not bring focus to that particular field anymore.

What I have tried is using `widgetVar` to execute focus. I declare a `widgetVar` name for my field, let say `widgetVar='username'`, and at the managed bean, I use the following code to focus it:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('username').focus()");
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Not sure if `execute()` doesn't work in this way or there is a problem with the statement. Sorry for my bad English, any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your Primefaces version?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Primefaces 6.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### PrimeFaces 6.3 and up

As mentioned in the comments, a utility method is available in the [`PrimeFaces` class](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/PrimeFaces.java):

```
PrimeFaces.current().focus(String expression)
```

where the expression is relative to the [view root](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html), or:

```
PrimeFaces.current().focus(String expression, UIComponent base)
```

where the expression is relative to the provided base component.

### Before PrimeFaces 6.3

Just check what PrimeFaces does in the [`focus` renderer](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/focus/FocusRenderer.java):

> ```
> ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
> UIComponent forComponent = SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponent(
>         context, focus, focus.getFor());
>
> String clientId = forComponent.getClientId(context);
>
> writer.write("$(function(){");
> writer.write("PrimeFaces.focus('" + clientId + "');");
> writer.write("});");
> ```

You can simply do the same in an action:

```
public void focus(String expression) {
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  UIComponent forComponent = SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponent(
    context,
    UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(context),
    expression
  );
  String clientId = forComponent.getClientId();
  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PrimeFaces.focus('" + clientId + "');");
}
```

Note that I'm using the command button that triggered the action as the source of the search expression and that you don't need `$(function(){...}` here.

The only thing you need to do is, instead of taking the `clientId` as an argument of the action method, create code to determine what component should receive focus.

Tested with XHTML:

```
<h:form id="main">
  <p:inputText id="text1"/>
  <p:inputText id="text2"/>
  <p:commandButton value="Focus 1" action="#{myBean.focus('text1')}"/>
  <p:commandButton value="Focus 2" action="#{myBean.focus('text2')}"/>
  <p:commandButton value="Form" action="#{myBean.focus('@form')}"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I think it's an good idea to add it to RequestContext (now PrimeFaces.current()). Will take care of it ot for 6.3: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3412